# Changing the size of a wx.ProgressDialog

Tags: python, wxpython, progressdialog

The size of the ProgresDialog is too narrow to hold the text that I need to display...
 I tryed to change the size of the dialog by calling the `SetSize` method on the dialog after it is created. 
This fixed the size of the dialog but on creation of the dialog the gauge size is initially smaller and then jumps in size to fit the dialog box size, which obviously looks nasty, is there any way to fix this or do I just have to create a custom dialog..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the ProgressDialog wraps the native platform dialog, so there may not be much you can do to fix it. To get the most flexibility, you'll have to use wx.Dialog and maybe a wx.Gauge.

---

Mike Driscoll

Blog:   http://blog.pythonlibrary.org

Comment: Thats what I thought -but wanted to be sure before... Thanks